# How to make jQuery UI to work in DotnetNuke 6+

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke

EDIT:
Here is the edited control file (control.ascx):

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Sale.ascx.cs" Inherits="Enmasse.Modules.Demo_Enmasse.Sale" %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=txtuser.ClientID%>").autocomplete('<%=ResolveUrl("Search_Username.ashx")%>');
        function AnotherJSFunction{
...
}
        });      
    </script>

    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex=0>
    <asp:View ID="main" runat="server">
    <div class=item>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtuser" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    ...
```

Here is the edited code behind file (control.ascx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
       {
            DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestUIRegistration();
       }
```

This is the web handler just in case (ashx):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Search_Username" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;

public class Search_Username : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Username from Users where Username like @SearchText + '%' and IsSuperUser <> 1";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(sdr["Username"]).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the web handler Search_Username.ashx and it works fine, but I'm not sure that the link to the file is correct. The jQuery autocomplete still doesn't work and there is no error either. I have no clue where to fix, although I have review some question on here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in DNN 6, jQuery UI is included in the framework.  Remove the JavaScript includes from your markup, and add `DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestUIRegistration` in the `Page_Load`.

From there, I would view source on the page and check that your URLs are correct.  Typically, I would use [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx), rather than `ModulePath` to get the path to a resource (e.g. `<%=ResolveUrl("Search_Username.ashx")%>`).

Otherwise it looks pretty reasonable.  You might look at the "[Remove with caching](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache)" example from jqueryui.com, and add some logging into the source method it provides, so you can see if you're actually wired-up, making calls, and getting responses.

Comment: I have done like you instructed, but still no result. Here is the real path to the ashx file: DesktopModules/MyModule/Search_username.ashx. And this is the url from the page source: '/dnn/DesktopModules/MyModule/Search_Username.ashx'. Is it correct?

Comment: It depends on how you have the site setup.  If it's at "localhost/dnn" then that should be the correct URL.  Try navigating there and see if you get what you expect...

Comment: Yes, my website is setup at "localhost/dnn", and I have tried to navigate to this file as well, and it returns value as I expected, but nothing happens. It's as if the auto complete function is not fired at all. I have updated the codes above, please see if I'm doing anything wrong. In the mean time, maybe I'll try the logging thing. Thanks

Comment: I have tried the logging thing and find something interesting. I saw this in the "Inspect element" console of Firebug: "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. " Is it an error?

Comment: That's just a warning that jQuery is referencing some event properties that are going to be removed.  It's not going to cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

*Since you're in DNN 6, jQuery UI is included in the framework. Remove the JavaScript includes from your markup, and add `DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestUIRegistration` in the `Page_Load`.